# Determine if $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

> Determine if $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$.

Computing the direct product I have that $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_3 = \{(x,y) \mid x \in \Bbb Z_2, y \in \Bbb Z_3 \} =\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)\}$ this has $6$ elements as does $\Bbb Z_6 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ I used this to conclude that the two groups are isomorphic, but I have a feeling that this doesn't count as a way to determine this. It seems that this could be done by looking at the orders of each group? I know that the order of a $g \in G$ is the smallest $n$ for which $g^n = e$, but I don't see how this can be used to show isomorphism?

Comment: In general this is not a good strategy for determining when two groups are isomorphic. Two groups may have the same number of elements, but in order to be isomorphic they must have, in a sense, the same group operation. If you're familiar with the Chinese Remainder theorem as Desperado linked to that's a good strategy, otherwise you need to construct an explicit isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are isomorphic, but having the same number of elements is not enough for that. Afer all $S_3$ also has $6$ elements, but it's not isomorphic to any of those two groups, which are abelian.

Simply define$$\begin{array}{rccc}\varphi\colon&\Bbb Z_6&\longrightarrow&\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_2\\&[n]&\mapsto&(n\pmod 3,n\pmod 2)\end{array}$$(that is, $\varphi(0)=(0,0)$, $\varphi(1)=(1,1)$, $\varphi(2)=(2,0)$, …). Now, prove that $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: As trivial as it is, maybe it worths noting that, since we are playing with classes by means of their representatives, first and foremost the "good definition" of $\varphi$ should be verified: $m\in[n]_6\Rightarrow ([m]_3=[n]_3)\wedge ([m]_2=[n]_2)$.

Comment: $\varphi$ is an isomorphism if it's bijective? Suppose that $\varphi(x) = \varphi(y)$, then $$(x \pmod{2}, x \pmod{3}) = (y \pmod{2}, y \pmod{3})$$ I'm not entirely sure if this immediately implies that $x = y$? Also for determining if $\varphi$ is onto I have that $y=(x \pmod{2}, x \pmod{3})$, but this doesn't seem to be very easy to work with?

Comment: @DanielLi Since $\varphi(0)=(0,0)$, $\varphi(1)=(1,1)$, $\varphi(2)=(2,0)$, $\varphi(3)=(0,1)$, $\varphi(4)=(1,0)$, and $\varphi(5)=(2,1)$, it is clear that $\varphi$ is a bijection.

Comment: @DanielLi, your will to formally prove, e.g., the injectivity is legitimate, and works: $\varphi([n]_6)=\varphi([m]_6)\Rightarrow ([n]_3,[n]_2)=([m]_3,[m]_2)\Rightarrow([n]_3=[m]_3)\wedge([n]_2=[m]_2)\Rightarrow [n]_6=[m]_6$. Incidentally, note that this proof is precisely the other direction than proving the good definition of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

By the Chinese remeinder Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), you have  $\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_q \cong \mathbb Z_{pq}$ if and ony if $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Answer (score 1):

There is an isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_3\to \mathbb{Z}_6$. 
Send $([1]_2,[1]_3)\mapsto [1]_6$ and $([0]_2,[0]_3)\mapsto [0]_6$, you can find out the mapping in detail from here, and then verify this is an isomorphism.